# Objective-C: Why not call the designated initializer?

Tags: objective-c, designated-initializer

I've inherited this code:

```
- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocation *)inLocation {
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _location = [inLocation copy];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocation *)inLocation offsetValue:(NSNumber *)offset {
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _location = [inLocation copy];
        _offset = [offset copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and am wondering if there's a good reason why the first method does not call the designated initializer (e.g. like this [Is it okay to call an init method in self, in an init method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495213/is-it-okay-to-call-an-init-method-in-self-in-an-init-method))?

i.e. why not do this:

```
- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocation *)inLocation {
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        [self initWithLocation:inLocation offsetValue:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocation *)inLocation offsetValue:(NSNumber *)offset {
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _location = [inLocation copy];
        _offset = [offset copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocation *)inLocation offsetValue:(NSNumber *)offset` method should be a designated initializer and the `- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocation *)inLocation` should call it like this:

```
- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocation *)inLocation {
    return [self initWithLocation:inLocation offsetValue:nil];
}
```

It's also considered a good practice to mark a designated initializer in the class interface using NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER:

```
- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocation *)inLocation offsetValue:(NSNumber *)offset NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

Comment: Given the answers are all much the same I'm picking this one as it mentioned the NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER.

Answer (score 0):

the much more appropriate way would be like this:

```
- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocation *)inLocation {
    return [self initWithLocation:inLocation offsetValue:nil];
}

- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocation *)inLocation offsetValue:(NSNumber *)offset {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _location = [inLocation copy];
        _offset = [offset copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you actually need to do is...

```
- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocation *)inLocation {
    return [self initWithLocation:inLocation offsetValue:nil];
}

- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocation *)inLocation offsetValue:(NSNumber *)offset {
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _location = [inLocation copy];
        _offset = [offset copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And you're right. There is no reason not to in this case.